# ASP.NET Browser Debug (support information) page

Tags: asp.net, browser

So one of the many many tasks I'm faced with daily as a developer is trying to get our support department to get as much information about the end users environment as possible.

Browser version, current cookies, plugins, etc etc and it would be handy to point people to a specific page on our site and say "copy paste this to support".

In the past I've always written these by hand, and used third party tools (such as BrowserHawk) to get as much info as possible.

How does everyone else deal with getting this information from end users, is there a nice package I'm unaware of to give a detailed dump a users env without having to get the users to run an app?

Just to clarify I'm not looking at an elmah style reporting (which is very helpful as well!) but this mainly for the client side stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some months ago I have see the googles ads page have a cool nice report button. What this button do is that capture using javacript the page as it is and send you the report, with all the details, and an image of the actually page.

So I have found this library http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ that make the same think.

And here are some example pages with this feedback.

http://hertzen.com/experiments/jsfeedback/

So I add this feedback option, and I ask from the users to point out the issue, and send the feedback, so for pages I have a very nice image for what is not going well.

The next think is that I log and check all errors, and I fix them soon.